# Showing different boolean columns in one plot in spotfire

Tags: bar-chart, visualization, data-visualization, spotfire

I have the following data structure to be displayed in spotfire
[image]

i'd like to have a visualization like this:
[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an unpivot of your table:

Click File > Add Data Tables. In the Add drop down box, choose the table that you want to unpivot. On the transformations section, choose Unpivot in the drop down box, and then press Add... Highlight all columns "Operations added Flag", "Operations Removed", etc and add them to the Columns to transform box. Note that you should only add the columns that you want to appear as bars. Hit OK. Next, add a bar chart. Right click and choose Horizontal Bars, and then again to choose 100% stacked. For the x-axis use `Count([Value])` and select `Category` for the y-axis. In the Bar Chart properties, change it so that it colors by `Value`.